# process values in php by explode function

Tags: php, arrays, explode

I have a string - a text of html

I want to explode the string by <'br> and <'p> in one line.

Thanks for the help in advance.

example

```
$text="hello <'p> this is the text <'br> split this text";

return

ar[0]=hello;

ar[1]=this is the text;

ar[2]=split this text;
```

Comment: Can you provide the example string?

Comment: more likely you want preg_split, as you have 2 delimiters

Comment: why are there quotes in those tags?

Comment: What about closing tags?? Do you have any?  I think a preg_split or regex would be better for this.

Comment: quotes are in there because for some reason <p> won't show up properly as preview - sorry for the newbie stuff :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this should suffice:

```
$text="hello <'p> this is the text <'br> split this text";
$string = str_replace(array("<'p> ", "<'br> "), '___', $text);

$ex = explode('___', $string);
```

Returning:

```
Array
(
    [0] => hello 
    [1] => this is the text 
    [2] => split this text
)
```

[**`Example`**](https://eval.in/166203)

Comment: i know this was the accepted answer but its really not the best.

Answer (score 2):

**EDIT**  -- using preg_split

```
$str = "text1<p>text2<br/>text3";
$str = preg_split('/(<\s*p\s*\/?>)|(<\s*br\s*\/?>)/', $str);
print_r($str);
//*note wont work with you <'p> <'br> tags, but only real "< p>< /p>< br/>" tags
```

Or with your quotes in the tags (dunno why theyre there but anyways)

```
 $str = "text1<'p>text2<'br>text3";
 $str = str_replace("<'p>","<'br>",$str);
 $values = explode("<'br>",$str);
 print_r($values);
```

Answer (score 1):

since the other 2 answers are terrible i suggest:

```
$text="hello <'p> this is the text <'br> split this text";
$e=preg_split("#<'p>|<'br>#",$text);
print_r($e);
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can...

```
$text = "hello <'p> this is the text <'br> split this text";
$text = str_replace("<'p>", "<'br>", $text);
$text = explode("<'br>", $text);
```

Now you get what you want.